# История написания слова "зарянка"

Tags: орфография

Коллеги, кто знает,  когда и с чьей легкой руки записали слово *зарянка* в исключения? В словарях  - зАрянка. В школьных учебниках на корни *зар-зор* тоже только одно исключение "зОревать". Но в различных учебных пособиях нет-нет (на протяжении 20 лет точно)да и всплывет: *"зОрянка" - исключение*. Особенно расстроило написание "зОрянка" в сборнике по подготовке к ГИА  по русскому языку (вполне официальном, централизованно изданном  в 2011 году). Честно говоря, я согласна с любым написанием, лишь бы единообразно и не приводило к ошибкам у детей. Я верю словарям. Интересно, на что опираются разработчики ГИА?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Историческое написание - как раз зорянка, в таком виде есть у Брокгауза и Ефрона. Поскольку названия представителей таксонимов (биологических классификационных единиц, т.е. видовые и родовые имена) в чем-то сродни именам собственным, они очень неохотно поддаются всякого рода орфографическим изменениям. Видимо, причина в этом.
Это не оправдание написания "зорянка" в современных текстах, только объяснение распространенности ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Если птица, то зарянка; если всполохи молний на горизонте, то зорянка.  И всё-таки два слова-исключения: зоревать и зорянка (всполохи молний )

Comment: Эта история с небесной зарянкой есть в интернете. В двух словах. 

Зорянка в значеии заря, зарница и проч. встречается только у Даля, тогдашняя орфография требовала О. При этом птица была названа зарянкой - вопреки тогдлашней орфографии. Ни один словарь того времени с Далем, вроде бы, не согласился, повсеместным было написание "зорянка" именно для птицы, о диалектном "зарянка"=зарница никто особо и не вспоминал.

После этого словари уже не разделяли написание. "Зорянка" якобы встречается ещё у Ожегова (в первых издланиях, сам не видел), но только как птица.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы! Позор мне, но значения "всполохи молний " у слова "зорянка" я не знала. Сколько пособий, справочников было перечитано - НИ В ОДНОМ не встречала про "всполохи". О! А может эта О ударная? Я по молодости "нашла ошибку " в учебнике в выражении "отбивать зОрю". Не знала. что ударение на первый слог.

Comment: У Лопатина: без ударения только А, в том числе зАрянка (птица). Никаких  исключений НЕТ. Даже и "зоревать" нет. 

У Даля (онлайн, у кого книга, проверьте. пожалуйста!) Никакой зОрянки. У него вот так:

ЗАРЯ, зарянка, заривать и пр. см. зарево.
А зарева в списке нет. Подозреваю ошибки в электронной версии

Comment: см. [здесь][1]: 

**Заревница** ж. или **заревницы** мн. день св. Феклы, 24 сентяб.
...
Зарница ж. зарники м. мн. сиб. зореница ниж. **зорянка** олон. отдаленная молния, когда виден свет и блеск ее, а грома не слышно, блискавица южн.


[1]http://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C_%D0%92._%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%E2%80%94_%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C